# Ruby: How to verify TCP connection alive

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

Server:

```
s = TCPServer.open(6000)
loop do
  Thread.start(s.accept) do |client|
    # Keep receive and handle message from client
    ...
  end
end
```

Clients:

```
server = TCPSocket.open(server_ip, 6000)
... # Send message if event, will keep TCP connection
```

Question:
Sometimes network down or client crash, How does sever know the TCP connection is alive? Is there a method or command the verify the connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to verify the state of a TCP connection is to send an empty packet to the server and check if you get a response or an error. That will give you the current connection state of the socket.